# Is there exception for out of bound in random generator?

Tags: exception, random

how to add exception with these case

```
Random random = new Random();
y=random.nextInt(50);
```

then if I ask user input and he enter 50+ value. is there such exception like out of bound in random?

Comment: What does this have to do with the random outcome?  You seem to be asking how to check user input, I don't see how your `y` ties in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `try` and `catch`

```
try
{
  if(y>50)
  throw new MyCustomException();
}

catch(MyCustomException ex)
{
  ex.ToString();
}
```